# Get robot pose in costmap layer updateBounds

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap-2d, costmap, layered-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get the pose of my robot in a custom costmap_2d layer, modeled after the tutorial layer here:
http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/Tutorials/Creating%20a%20New%20Layer
The robot_x, robot_y, and robot_yaw parameters in the updateBounds function don't seem to change from zero throughout the planning process. Is there any other way to get the pose of the robot in that function? Or some way to see why the pose is zero? I can't seem to find where that function is called. The changes I make to the costmap are applied, though. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213454/get-robot-pose-in-costmap-layer-updatebounds./) by [mattc_vec](https://answers.ros.org/users/22656/mattc_vec/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2015-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The function is called here:
https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/jade-devel/costmap_2d/src/layered_costmap.cpp#L98

The numbers passed in should reflect the pose of the robot_base_frame relative to the global frame. I would check the frame of your map.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0